# Ŧ & ŧ with Computer Modern font (u+0166 & u+0167 – Latin letter T with stroke)

Tags: unicode, characters

Is it possible to get the Unicode characters below into Latex ordinary computer modern — normal, italic and bold ?

- Ŧ : `u+0166` (Latin capital letter t with stroke)
- ŧ : `u+0167` (Latin lower case letter t with stroke)

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  "ordinary computer modern" has a severely restricted space limitation, so it would be essentially impossible.  for computer modern implemented as an opentype font, it would be possible, but whether it would be likely, i can't say.

Comment: @barbarabeeton depends how you define "into" cm has t T and various dashes so you can construct something from bits

Comment: is this letter to be used in words (that might want to be hyphenated), or is it just to be used as a standalone symbol?

Comment: The letters are available in the T4 encoding at slots `"9F` and `"BF`. Unfortunately, T4 encoded fonts are only available for the `cmr` family and in bitmap form.

Comment: @egreg: T4 encoded fonts are available also for the `cmss` and `cmtt` families. In addition there is a `cmst` family (Sans serif typewriter).

Comment: @jknappen You're right; I was lazy and intended Computer Modern in the various family. Any hope that the fonts get deployed in Type1 format?

Comment: @egreg: Unfortunately, I cannot tell because I do not create Type 1 fonts. Maybe it is already possible using the CMU fonts as base, I haven't checked the full repertoire of CMU.

Answer (score 5):

It is in `CM Unicode`, but not in `Latin Modern`, so you can use it with `fontspec` and XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX: as the default for fontspec is Latin Modern, you have to specify you use CM unicode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

Here it is:

 Ŧ ŧ

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hei, I got the following error message when comipling: % fontspec error: "font-not-found", The font "CMU Serif" cannot be found

Comment: Is cm-unicode installed on your system?

Comment: Hello, I really do not know. I use the: The MacTeX-2016 Distribution and the TeXShop editor. Without any additions. Kjetil

Comment: Your last comment seems incomplete. Did you check with TeX Live Utility?

Comment: Hei, It works with LuaLateX!!! -- But not in XeLateX. The italic an sans serif fonts did not work.

Comment: For me works with both.  The sans serif font does not have this glyph. As to the italic, it is supposed to exist, but I obtain an error message. Same for bold extended.

Answer (score 3):

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you just input the characters and, if the current font has glyphs for them, you'll get them.

If you happen to use a font that doesn't have the glyphs, under XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can build them (I assume the font has U+00AF MACRON). Of course this requires supplying *ad hoc* definitions that must be crafted for each desired style. Here's one that works for upright fonts; don't try them with italics. `;-)` However, it shouldn't be too difficult to add some horizontal kerning when the font is slanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{relsize,newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{ŧ}{\texttstroke}
\newunicodechar{Ŧ}{\textTstroke}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\texttstroke}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \sbox0{\larger[-1]\kern-.05em\symbol{"AF}}%
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      {\larger[-1]\kern-.05em\symbol{"AF}}\cr
      \noalign{\kern-\ht0 \kern-.7ex}
      t\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textTstroke}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \sbox0{\symbol{"AF}}%
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \symbol{"AF}\cr
      \noalign{\kern-\ht0 \kern-.86ex}
      T\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

ŧŦ

\large ŧŦ

\huge ŧŦ

\small ŧŦ

\footnotesize ŧŦ

\end{document}
```

[image]

With some changes, the macros can work also with `pdflatex`. Here the code is a bit more complex, to ensure it works with all engines, but the idea is to define `\tstroke` in a suitable way depending on the engine. The `pdflatex` version uses `\={}` (the macron accent).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}

\newif\ifunicodeengine
\ifxetex\unicodeenginetrue\fi
\ifluatex\unicodeenginetrue\fi

\ifunicodeengine
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \newcommand{\tstroke}{\symbol{"AF}}
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \newcommand{\tstroke}{\={}}
\fi

\usepackage{newunicodechar,relsize}

\newunicodechar{ŧ}{\texttstroke}
\newunicodechar{Ŧ}{\textTstroke}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\texttstroke}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \sbox0{\larger[-1]\kern-.05em\tstroke}%
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      {\larger[-1]\kern-.05em\tstroke}\cr
      \noalign{\kern-\ht0 \kern-.7ex}
      t\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textTstroke}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \sbox0{\tstroke}%
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \tstroke\cr
      \noalign{\kern-\ht0 \kern-.86ex}
      T\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

ŧŦ

\large ŧŦ

\huge ŧŦ

\small ŧŦ

\footnotesize ŧŦ

\end{document}
```

Here's a version that adds the kerning when the current font is slanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}

\newif\ifunicodeengine
\ifxetex\unicodeenginetrue\fi
\ifluatex\unicodeenginetrue\fi

\ifunicodeengine
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \newcommand{\tstroke}{\symbol{"AF}}
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \newcommand{\tstroke}{\={}}
\fi

\usepackage{newunicodechar,relsize}

\newunicodechar{ŧ}{\texttstroke}
\newunicodechar{Ŧ}{\textTstroke}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\texttstroke}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \sbox0{\larger[-1]\kern-.05em\tstroke}%
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \ifdim\fontdimen1\font>0pt \kern-.1em\fi
      {\larger[-1]\kern-.05em\tstroke}\cr
      \noalign{\kern-\ht0 \kern-.7ex}
      t\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textTstroke}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \sbox0{\tstroke}%
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \ifdim\fontdimen1\font>0pt \kern-.15em\fi
      \tstroke\cr
      \noalign{\kern-\ht0 \kern-.86ex}
      T\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\itshape

ŧŦ

\large ŧŦ

\huge ŧŦ

\small ŧŦ

\footnotesize ŧŦ

\end{document}
```

The output for upright letters is as before. Here's the output for italics.

[image]

The various dimensions should be adapted to the main text font, of course.

An alternative for `pdflatex` is using T4 encoded fonts that, however, are only available in bitmap form. The glyphs are encoded at slots `"97` and `"B7`, so this can be quickly set up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T4,T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0167}{\texttstroke}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0166}{\textTstroke}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\texttstroke}{T4}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textTstroke}{T4}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\texttstroke}{T4}{"97}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textTstroke}{T4}{"B7}


\begin{document}

tŧŦT

\large tŧŦT

\huge tŧŦT

\small tŧŦT

\footnotesize tŧŦT

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0167}{\texttstroke}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0166}{\textTstroke}
\newcommand\texttstroke{t\llap{-\kern.07em}}
\newcommand\textTstroke{T\raise.1ex\llap{-\,}}
\begin{document}

[ŧ][Ŧ]

\end{document}
```

Comment: but if this letter needs to be put in a context that might need to be hyphenated, it would prevent that, no?

Comment: @barbarabeeton of course yes, or rather you'd need to mark hyphenation points with `\-` but that already applies to several characters that are supported by default in inputenc, and almost all of them if the real computer modern, OT1 font is used

Comment: Hei, I am very sorry, compiling this code gave me: Undefined control sequence --- \DeclareUnicodeCharacter.  Regards Kjetil

Comment: @KjetilHåkonPettersen did you use exactly the code above, with `inputenc` ? It is hard to see how you can get that error from the posted code

Comment: @KjetilHåkonPettersen did you use pdftex?

Comment: No I am using XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

Comment: @KjetilHåkonPettersen your question is in that case completely misleading (and this answer is not appropriate at all) "Latex ordinary computer modern"  implies the original (7bit) computer modern font with classic latex. I stretched it a bit to 8bit fonts here but if you meant unicode you should have said:-) No harm done though but you should accept bernard's answer...